# Broken icon is displayed for the image with alt text

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an image called `image.jpg` inside the `src` -> `images` -> `image.jpg`. I have some problem with my image on my React app. My code is running well but the image does not show up instead on saving and loading the application, the image is not displayed but broken icon is displayed with alt text. How is it possible to solve this problem?

What I have tried is:

```
import React from "react";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      term: "",
      names: [
        { name: "Deepak", job_profile: "Quality Analyst", description: "He is Passionate in Tester" },
        { name: "Deepinder", job_profile: "iOS Developer", description: "He is a Dedicated iOS Developer" }
      ],
      filteredData: [{}]
    };
  }

  render() {
    let terms = "";
    if (this.state.term) {
      terms = this.state.term.toLowerCase();
    }
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <label>Search Employee: </label>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={this.state.term}
          id="searchEmp"
          placeholder="Enter Name"
          onChange={(event) => {
            if (event.target.value.indexOf(" ") > -1) {
              alert("Please don\'t enter space.");
              this.setState({ term: "" });
              return;
            }
            this.setState({ term: event.target.value });
          }}
        />
        <br />
        <br />

        {this.state.names &&
          this.state.names
            .filter((x) => x.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(terms) || (x.description.toLowerCase().includes(terms)))
            .map((item) => {
              return (
                <div className="data-body">
                  <div>Name : {item.name}</div>
                  <div>Job Profile : {item.job_profile}</div>
                  <div>Description : {item.description}</div>
                  <div><img src={require('../src/images/image.jpg')} alt="profile_picture" /></div>
                  <input type="button" id="button" 
                  value="Delete" onClick={() => {
                  this.setState
                  ({ names: this.state.names.filter
                  (i => i.name !== item.name) });
                  }}/>
                  <div>{<br></br>}</div>
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
          );
        }
}
export default App;
```

Comment: I think u need to check whether the image exists or is correctly referenced

Comment: @Banny-is my code okay? I mean there might be an error of path or existence of image. What according to you code is right or not.

Comment: your code looks fine, you can put your images in the public folder and reference them like this   <img src='/image.jpg' alt="profile_picture" />

Comment: hope that works fine

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you are using create-react-app to bundle your project. If that is the case, you just need to put all your images in the public folder and just mention the name in the src attribute.

You don't need the require function while mentioning the source of an image.

So, your code should look like this:

```
<img src="image.jpg" alt="profile_picture"/>
```

If you want the image to reside in some part of your source directory, you can import the image from there and use it in your code as follows:

```
import Image from '../images/image.jpg'
<img src={Image} alt="profile_picture"/>
```

**Edit**

Using ES5 syntax, you could do the following:

```
const Image = require("../images/image.jpg")
<img src={Image} alt="profile_picture"/>
```

Comment: @Near-the second you've suggested I'd tried but I want to display image(s) using `required`. For the same, could you please write down?

Comment: @xKodian I have updated the answer with ES5 syntax too

Answer (score 0):

**i hope this helps you**

```
<div>
 <img src='../src/images/image.jpg' alt="profile_picture" />
</div>
```